# induced map between cohomology groups of real projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $i: \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$. Then $i$ induces isomorphisms $i^*: H^k(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)\longrightarrow H^k(\mathbb{R}P^{n-1};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ for $0\leq k\leq n-2$. Why $i^*$ is also isomorphism for $k=n-1$?

page 212 bottom line 7 of Allen Hatcher's algebraic topology.  Without this stronger claim, the following proof by induction does not hold.

On page~91 of Lecture Notes on Algebraic Topology II, John Rognes, November, 2012, the proof is same as above. Hence we should not doubt on the validity.

Could any one give a help? Im really grateful!

Comment: This is false for $k=n-1$. Probably just a typo.

Comment: but without this stronger claim, the following proof by induction does not hold.

Comment: OK, but then you should ask a different question.

Comment: False? Who says?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I just misread the dimensions. The isomorphism indeed holds for $k-1$. One way to see it is to use Poincare duality, alternatively, use the standard cell complex decomposition of the projective space as in Ted's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should follow directly from the fact that $\mathbb RP^{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-skeleton of $\mathbb RP^n$ and the fact that, with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients, all the boundary maps are $0$.

Comment: So always hold for $n-1$-skeleton of an arbitrary $n$-manifold?

Comment: Um, no, I've edited. One must be very careful. We could have a cell complex where the boundary of the $n$-cell is $1$ times the $(n-1)$-skeleton. But for a compact, $F$-oriented $n$-dimensional manifold, the $F$-fundamental class has no boundary.

Comment: Thank you a lot Prof. Ted Shifrin!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if you're satisfied, so this will go off the "unanswered" list :)

Comment: thanks to your help, I am already clear ha